# Teradata Conversion of difference between dates in hours

Tags: teradata

I need to calculate the difference between 2 dates i.e creation date till todays date in hours in teradata.

```
((Creation_date - Current_Date) HOUR) As Open_Hour
```

Comment: Are those columns actually DATEs or TIMESTAMPs? What's the rule for partial hours?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want hours:

```
select current_timestamp - <your timestamp> hour
```

If you want to get more granular, you can use `hour to minute` or `hour to second`.